# Significance of white space in CSS rules

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS and am wondering what is the correct way to write CSS as I have found conflicting information online.

`body {background-color: red;}`
`body {background-color:red;}`

The difference between the two examples above is the space after the selector's colon. I have read in different places that both of these examples are correct.

Which of these is correct? Is there any consequence of using the wrong one?

Comment: The `selector` is the bit outside the brackets. White space might be significant here. White space is generally not significant inside the brackets. See the [W3C Selector reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Comment: If you use a minifier, it will remove those spaces. Easiest to write the code with spacing that makes it readable, and use a minifier to strip it out for serving up to the public.

Comment: The only difference is consistency and readability. Since you're interested in this topic, I suggest reading [Code Guide](https://codeguide.co/): Standards for developing consistent, flexible, and sustainable HTML and CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really matter whether you leave a space or not. `selector {property:value;}` will achieve the same as `selector {property: value}`.

Answer (score 1):

The rendering engines don't care about the white space, if it exists, between the CSS property and the value. So in short, it doesn't matter. If you are using a minified `.css` file then those spaces will be removed anyway.

`color: red;` is the same thing as `color:red;`